# JavaScript Error for CodaSlider

Tags: javascript

I am getting a JavaScript Error, and you can see this here:
http://www.northernvirginiapaintingcontractor.com/Interior

Object doesn't support this property or method
for this line:

```
$(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
```

If anyone has any clue, please let me know I would really appreciate it.

This line is included here- the entire JavaScript for this CodaSlider: (except Coda Plugin)

```
    var theInt = null;
    var $crosslink, $navthumb;
    var curclicked = 0;

    theInterval = function (cur) {
        clearInterval(theInt);

        if (typeof cur != 'undefined')
            curclicked = cur;

        $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
        $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
        $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');

        theInt = setInterval(function () {
            $crosslink.removeClass("active-thumb");
            $navthumb.eq(curclicked).parent().addClass("active-thumb");
            $(".stripNav ul li a").eq(curclicked).trigger('click');
            curclicked++;
            if (7 == curclicked)
                curclicked = 0;

        }, 3000);
    };
```

Here is the document ready function:

```
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // slider below //
                $("#main-photo-slider").codaSlider();

                $navthumb = $(".nav-thumb");
                $crosslink = $(".cross-link");

                $navthumb
                .click(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    theInterval($this.parent().attr('href').slice(1) - 1);
                    return false;
                });
             .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside the console on your website:

`typeof $ === 'undefined'` // true

`typeof jQuery === 'undefined'` // false

Moving this chunk of code (line 153-178) inside of the call to `jQuery(function ($) {...}` on line 181 should solve the problem.